# Why does 'extern template class' technique not work as expected?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, templates, compiler-errors

***The original question has been refined.***

Given a source code file named `main.cpp` as follows:

```
#include <string>
extern template class std::basic_string<char>;

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    T n = {};

    T get() const
    {
        return n;
    }
};

extern template struct A<int>;

int main()
{
    auto a = A<int>{}.get(); // undefined reference to `A<int>::get() const'
    auto b = static_cast<int>(std::string{}.size()); // ok

    return a + b;
}
```

**What I expected:**

Note that the source code has `extern template class std::basic_string<char>` but no `template class std::basic_string<char>`.

So, the compiler would not instantiate class `std::basic_string<char>`, then `g++ main.cpp` would cause link errors on line `std::string{}.size()` as on line `A<int>{}.get()`.

**What I observed:**

It is ok to `g++ main.cpp` on line `std::string{}.size()`. [Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YW8x35rE8)

**Why does** `extern template class` **technique not work as expected?**

Comment: both g++ 12.1 and clang++ 13.0 are ok.

Comment: change class to struct

Comment: @JaMiT now is compilable

Comment: What symbol do you expect to be undefined?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. see my refined question.

Comment: Why do you think `std::basic_string<char>` is not explicitly instantiated somewhere in the standard library?

Comment: I include <string> only. Is it implementation-defined that whether a standard class will be  explicitly instantiated in its headers? @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: You link with the standard library. You do not control which instantiations it may contain. ODR violations are NDR anyway, so don't expect your program to be rejected because of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two reasons why it doesn't work.

**One** There is no prohibition against library class and function template instantiations being declared as `extern template` by the implementation. `gcc` and `libstdc++` do just that.

```
$ g++ -E main.cpp | grep 'extern.*string'
extern template class basic_string<char>;      // <-- from the library
extern template class basic_string<wchar_t>;   // <-- from the library
extern template class std::basic_string<char>; // <-- your line
```

The standard library implementation contains the explicit instantiation definitions (you can dig the source).

**Two** An entity that is the subject of an explicit instantiation declaration and that is also used in a way that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation in the translation unit shall be the subject of an explicit instantiation definition somewhere in the program; otherwise the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required [[temp.explicit](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#13)].

A possible rationale for the NDR is that `extern template` should not prevent inlining and other uses that do not involve linking. Indeed, with `-O2` `A::get` is inlined, and the program builds just fine. There is no established technology that would force this program to be rejected no matter what. It *can* be rejected because of linker errors, but there is no requirement for linker errors to appear.